# Understanding/Visualizing Complex Numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

So I've always imagined complex numbers as a point in a 2D plane.
Is this a problem? Is there a fundamental difference between a point on a 2D plane and a complex number? Will I have issues with more advance concepts regarding complex numbers due to such a visualization? How should I otherwise imagine complex numbers?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with that. The thing is that complex numbers, as a set, can be thought as the points on a plane. But you have more than a set. Namely, you have a set with a structure defined on it. You can add and multiply numbers and certain rules are satisfied. This is what they call a field. This structure is actually more fundamental than the set itself. You can actually replace the set by a different "substrate".

For example, the vector space $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be identified with the set of points on a plane too. But it is a completely different animal, it has a different structure. You cannot multiply vectors, for example.

Comment: As DEATH_CUBE_K mentions, you can identify them at the level of topological spaces. If you are not interested in the algebraic structure, there is no way to distinguish them. It is all about the structure.

Answer (score 1):

I would say there's no harm in viewing them this way since, as vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{C}$ are isomorphic. Regarding *visualization*, it might help your studies down the line if you think of a slightly modified geometric representation of complex numbers: every complex number can be written as $z=re^{i\theta}$. In this case $r$ is the absolute value, and $\theta$ describes the angle between the positive real axis and the number represented as a vector. So if you multiply two complex numbers $z_1=r_1e^{i\theta_1}$ and $z_2=r_2e^{i\theta_2}$, this corresponds to multiplying their absolute values and adding their phases and you'll end up with a complex number of the form $z_3=r_1r_2e^{i(\theta_1+\theta_2)}$. Without adopting this view further in your studies, you might not be able to appreciate what's happening geometrically.

Visualizing complex numbers as so as opposed to merely points in a set has helped me tremendously when thinking about their applications in AC circuits with apparent power, frequency responses, filtering, and sinusoidal voltage/current sources since their behavior is intrinsically described using complex numbers.

Answer (score 0):

As topological spaces, $\mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{R}^2$ so it is perfectly reasonable (and useful) to identify a complex number with a ordered pair of real numbers.